# AsEnumerable() Why is this not working as in VB

Tags: c#

Hey people i have this code that is mostly like the one i use in asp.net VB
But why is not working  in C# ( PD: "Im new on C#")

```
public List<Historico> Consultar_Todos()
{           
    return Glovar.ListHistorico.asEnumerable(); 
}
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do, and what is it actually doing?

Comment: And what VB code are you talking about?

Comment: Because in VB, you probably had `Option Strict Off` and it automatically converted the type for you.  C# acts like VB with `Option Strict On`.  There is no equivalent for turning the strict type casting off in C#.

Comment: Either that or it's the problem that VB is not case sensitive but C# is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want to be returning a List call `ToList`

```
public List<Historico> Consultar_Todos()
{           
   return Glovar.ListHistorico.ToList(); 
}
```

**NOTE**  C# is case sensitive if you wanted to return an IEnumerable you need to change the return type to IEnumerable and the method call to AsEnumerable()

like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Historico> Consultar_Todos()
{           
    return Glovar.ListHistorico.AsEnumerable(); 
}
```

Comment: 2nd option here is better than the first.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, Agreed, but both seem like a bad choice since they're dumping the whole table.